# Not able to see updated stored procedure parameters in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I modified one stored procedure in SQL server 2008 but i'm not able to see my modified column names in crystal report 6 version(able to see in the database). What i did is removed old SProc and added modified one to same report through option database - add database to report, but i'm not able to save, its through errors..

Anyone help me to resolve this issue..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of removing the stored procedure and re-adding it, simply go to `Database -> Verify Database` to force your report to see the modified procedure.