# change server connection in crystal report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, report

I have a crystal report file that select data with parameters from SQL server DB, but I changed the database to another server(03) so I changed the connection string in the crystal report file but the parameter still see the last server 02,now how do i force the parameter to enter values on the new server 03
thanks all

Answer (score 1):

update again database by : **Select Database menu > Set Datasource Location.**

[Force to update parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365637/not-able-to-see-updated-stored-procedure-parameters-in-crystal-report)

[How do I point Crystal Reports at a new database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128659/how-do-i-point-crystal-reports-at-a-new-database)

[update connection](http://kb.bqe.com/questions.php?questionid=409)